# How can I know the URI of the SIlent ringtone?

Tags: android, file, path, uri, ringtonemanager

I need the URI of the Silent sound from the Ringtone Manager. Does anyone knows how can I get this URI. Is it static from phone to phone.

I have already tried to create empty .mp3 and .wav sound files, but it simply does not work (The app that receives the URI does not replace the current notification sound).

I've seen that the URI of a Silent sound would simply be an empty string "", but it did not work as well.

```
var profileConfig = {
"PROFILE_NAME": $parameters.ProfileName,
"PROFILE_ENABLED": "true",
"CONFIG_MODE": "UPDATE",
"PLUGIN_CONFIG": {
"PLUGIN_NAME": "BARCODE",
"RESET_CONFIG": "true",
"PARAM_LIST": {
"decode_audio_feedback_uri": ""
}
},
"APP_LIST": [{
"PACKAGE_NAME": $parameters.AppName,
"ACTIVITY_LIST": ["*"]
}]
};

sendCommand("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", profileConfig);
```

This is what I am doing. Basically, after decode_audio_feedback_uri, I need to send the URI of a file from the RingtoneManager and it will be send to another app via android intent to deal with the uri.

Comment: Are you sure there's a silent ringtone, and it isn't just lack of any ringtone?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just specify an empty string, you need to load a silent ringtone and install it on the device first:

- Generate silence.mp3
- Copy silence.mp3 to the device
- Load the DataWedge profile associated with your app.  Go to Barcode Input: Configure Scanner Settings --> Scan Params --> Decode Audio Feedback --> (Scroll to the bottom) --> Add ringtone
- Specify the new ringtone within your code as "silence". Similar to https://github.com/darryncampbell/Appforum_2019_DataWedge_API/blob/master/CaptureData/app/src/main/java/com/darryncampbell/capturedata/DataWedgeUtilities.java#L43

See also related issue https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedgeCordova/issues/6